# SSL TLS1.2 based REST webservice in java

Tags: java, rest, ssl, tls1.2

I need to develop a ssl tls1.2 based rest webservice in java, I have written simple rest webservice in java. What should I need to add to the code to make it SSL TLS1.2 enabled one.

```
package nit.ws;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

@Path("/test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Path("/hi")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHi()
    {
        return "Hi, welcome to rest world";
    }



    @GET
    @Path("/pdf")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public javax.ws.rs.core.Response getPdf() throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\juke\\Desktop\\learning.pdf");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok((Object) fileInputStream);
        responseBuilder.type("application/pdf");
        responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "filename=test.pdf");
        return responseBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: on what server do you deploy your app ?

Comment: I am deploying it on wildfly server.

Comment: For TLS 1.2 support use an recent Wildfly and Java version (e.g. Java 11). They should use TLS 1.2 out of the box. Of course you still have to provide a matching SSL/TLS certificate plus private key.